# Docker volume files don't appear in host

Tags: docker, volume

EDIT: First post, I'm trying to get some formatting...
I want to mount a host directory into a container directory so I can get container-created files back into the host.  I've investigated at least a dozen examples with no luck.  As near as I can tell, the following *should* work.

```
C:\tmp>ls -al jmeter
total 0
drwxrwxrwx   1 0        0               0 May 22 19:25 .
drwxrwxrwx   1 0        0               0 May 22 19:36 ..

C:\tmp>docker run -v /tmp/jmeter:/tmp/jmeter -it ubuntu bash
root@62a046b1dd74:/# ls -al /tmp/jmeter
total 4
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root   40 May 23 02:00 .
drwxrwxrwt 1 root root 4096 May 23 02:00 ..
root@62a046b1dd74:/# touch /tmp/jmeter/bob.txt
root@62a046b1dd74:/# ls -al /tmp/jmeter
total 4
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root   60 May 23 02:01 .
drwxrwxrwt 1 root root 4096 May 23 02:00 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    0 May 23 02:01 bob.txt
root@62a046b1dd74:/# exit
exit

C:\tmp>ls -al jmeter</b>
total 0
drwxrwxrwx   1 0        0               0 May 22 19:25 .
drwxrwxrwx   1 0        0               0 May 22 19:36 ..

C:\tmp>
```

My expectation is that /tmp/jmeter/bob.txt would exist on localhost. 
FWIW, localhost is Windows 10 here, but I have the same problem in a github action, which I believe is Linux.

Comment: you are using  C:\tmp which gives me an impression its windows.. but you are showing output of linux ls..

Comment: hope you have shared your c: in docker settings

Comment: try this
docker run -v c:/tmp/jmeter:/tmp/jmeter  -it ubuntu bash

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to debug on Windows.  The problem initially presented in a github action.  Locally, I have added c:/tmp as a docker sharepoint.  I just added c:/tmp/jmeter as a public windows sharepoint, but it made no difference.

Comment: Hope the Powershell is opened in Admin mode..

Comment: Hey! Adding the c: in the source works locally. Thanks.  Now to figure out why it doesn't work in the github action.

Comment: Linux try  without c:  -v /tmp/jmeter:/tmp/jmeter